# How to use any letter from any langugage in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

**Use case:**

I have the following string `'파이어 볼'` and I want to check if each symbol in the string is a valid letter in any language.

**What I've tried:**

To do this, I found the following regex pattern that is supposed to match "any letter in any language".

```
/\p{L}/
```

The pattern successfully matched on the major regex helper websites (regex101, regexcoach, regexer) I tested. They all returned the 4 symbols as matches, as intended.

Now when I try this in my javascript/node.js application it doesn't work, see the following snippet:

```js
if (/\p{L}/.test('파이어 볼')) {
  alert('true'); 
}
else {
  alert('false');
}
```

**Question:**

How can I properly test if a given character is a valid letter in **any** language.

Comment: can you please explain which can be invalid characters?

Comment: @programtreasures all "non-letter" characters, such as interpunction, numbers, non printable, control-characters and so on

Comment: JS regex does not support `\p{L}` and similar; you were probably testing with a flavor like PCRE which supports it. There are alternatives that have been suggested already, for example my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37668315/6083675).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript doesn't properly unicode regex.
Use this library as it fixes the missing functionality:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-regex-pl